# whois package cannot be imported

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to get this simple package working with my django project, but it's not working:

https://github.com/DannyCork/python-whois

**Steps I took**:

1. pip install whois
2. Within my views.py

import whois

Error that I got: 
**Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whois'**

Any thoughts on why I can't import this?

Apparently this package only runs on linux, so I'm not running this on my local machine. This is the error I got when running on my linux webserver.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check where is `pip` installing the package and where is python installed ? This can be caused because of the path not added to `sys path`

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to run the pip install whois command on my server :S